# ApplicationDomain: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed when instantiating class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've made a simple project to reproduce the problem. The code is at the bottom of the description.

Situation: my app loads one swf file from the network. The swf contains two simple button classes - ClassA, ClassB, and one panel ClassC, which contains both buttons in it.

When I try to instantiate ClassC after the swf is loaded, using `applicationDomain.getDefinition("ClassC")`, it works.

Next, I load another swf file, which contains class called mvFish. I try to instantiate it, and it works too.

Next, I try to instantitate ClassC again, and it gives the error:

`[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@560ed61 to ClassA.`

The error refers not to ClassC which I'm trying to instantiate, but to ClassA inside it.

UPDATE -- Changing ApplicationDomain does not help -- details on problem:

All class definitions are still available - I can get a definition for A, B, C or mvFish.

A, B and mvFish can still be instantiated (because they don't contain children).

C can instantiate if its children are not exported as classes.

If they are exported as classes, C tries to instantiate but there is a error where its children (A and B) are created. Looks like a Movieclip is taken and being cast to ClassA and fails. If I remove class A, the errors happens with class B. It happens with any child class.

If I create any kind of `ApplicationDomain`, use it in `LoaderContext` and then try to get definition from it, it returns `null` and `getQualifiedDefinitionNames()` gives empty list. Works only via loader property path so it seems the loader somehow has different domain.

If I load the first swf again, problem disappears. It's like each time I need a class from other swf, I need to reload it.

This is how first swf library looks, nothing complicated:

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/ca7473e31331a7dc93d349fa0bb8055c.png]

Here is the sample code from FlashDevelop project:

```
package {
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
    import flash.system.LoaderContext;
    import flash.system.Security;
    import flash.system.SecurityDomain;
    import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite {

        private var asset:Loader;
        private var lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(true, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);

        public function Main():void {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
            Security.allowDomain("*");
            var l:Loader = new Loader();
            l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, firstComplete);
            // loading first asset
            l.load(new URLRequest("http://zdg.ru/tmp/test_asset.swf"), lc);
        }

        private function firstComplete(evt:Event):void {
            asset = evt.target.loader;
            var mc:Class = asset.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("ClassC") as Class;
            new mc() as Sprite; // trying to instantiate ClassC -- OK!
            var l:Loader = new Loader();
            l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, secondComplete);
            // loading the second asset
            l.load(new URLRequest("http://zdg.ru/tmp/Fish.swf"), lc);
        }

        private function secondComplete(evt:Event):void {
            var mc:Class = evt.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition("mvFish") as Class;
            new mc() as Sprite; // trying to instantiate mvFish -- OK!
            mc = asset.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("ClassC") as Class;
            new mc() as Sprite; // trying to instantiate ClassC again -- Error!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not a 100% if it is your problem but to load an swf with a new context just declare one like this `var myContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain(), null);` and use it as a parameter with `myLoader.load(myURLReq, myContext);` i'd link the official as3 reference but it seems offline to me

Comment: You are the one creating those problems for yourself. I'm guessing you don't use (or never use) any package and have the same class names used in different places. Of course you are creating conflicts that's what packages allow you to avoid.

Comment: No, the given code is the only code. There are no other classes, no different places. You can compile it and see.

Comment: @MartonPallagi Unfortunately, `lc = new LoaderContext(true, new ApplicationDomain());` before the second load does not help, the error is the same.

Comment: no other classes? So you mean there are no exported library symbols involved (lexported ibrary symbols are classes of course)? That's the opposite of what you say in your question. getDefinition only works on classes so how can you say there are no other classes when obviously you are trying to instantiate ClassC, etc ...

Comment: Yes, no OTHER classes. Only ClassA, ClassB, ClassC and mvFish, and no other. I'm not stupid, you know.

Comment: what does `mc` trace to before the error?

Comment: then what I said still applies and is the reason for your problem, class name conflict.

Comment: @MartonPallagi `trace(mc)` gives `[class ClassC]`. It has no problem getting class reference, but cannot instantiate it. Additionally, if I get definition for `ClassA`, it will give me it too, without any problems, and will even instantiate it.

Comment: @BotMaster there are classes A,B,C exported in one swf's library and class mvFish exported in other swf's library. Can you elaborate, what class conflicts with what class after I loaded both swfs?

Comment: You have 2 ClassA and once one override the other you can't instantiate the first one anymore.

Comment: @BotMaster - where do I have 2 ClassA? I have only one in the first swf, and I load it only once. I don't have ClassA anywhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real aswer, but the code I posted wasn't working yesterday but it magically works today. -- UPDATE -- Oh forget about it, it doesn't work.

Finally, I found the cause. It doesn't work strictly for two reasons:

1) The ClassC contains ClassA which is a SimpleButton. Yes, only buttons are bad, and only those buttons that are contained inside other DisplayObjects.  Make it a MovieClip, and it will work. Instantiate the button directly with no container, and it will work too.

2) The project is running locally. Put it to the hosting and it will work like a charm, with buttons or whatever.

So the last question: how to set up FlashDevelop to work with the loaded assets locally?